# Hallar el promedio del resultado de un int en c#

Tags: c#, funciones

me pidieron hallar el promedio del resultado "aprobados", ya intente de varias formas pero no logro resolverlo.
Alguien podría darme una mano, por favor. Saludos a todos.

```
   case 2:

                        Console.Clear();

                       int aprobados = 0;
                       int reprobados = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < colNumeros.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (colNumeros[i] >= 70)
                            {
                                aprobados++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                reprobados++;
                            }

                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("aprobados: " + aprobados);
                        Console.WriteLine("reprobados: " + reprobados);
                        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Faltan detalles para dar una respuesta, necesita clarificacion, lo unico que puedo hacer es hacer conjeturas sobre por ejemplo colNumeros.Count es el numero total de alumnos que es un dato necesario para hallar el promedio.

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Comment: Muchachos, muchas gracias por su aporte, "Javp" seguramente estas a otro nivel ya que aun no he llegado a trabajar con las funciones que planteaste. Te agradezco el tiempo. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende bien la pregunta, pero, si es el promedio de las notas de los aprobados deberías hacer un contador para sumar las notas de los aprobados  el resultado final dividirlo por la cantidad de aprobados.

```
int aprobados=0;
int reprobados=0;
int sumaNotas=0;
for (int i = 0; i < colNumeros.Count; i++)
{
   if (colNumeros[i] >= 70)
   {
      aprobados++;
      sumaNotas+=colNumeros[i];
   }
   else
   {
      reprobados++;
   }
}
Console.WriteLine("Promedio aprobados: " + sumaNotas/aprobados);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Federico, al final lo resolvimos en clase de esta manera, gracias por tu tiempo!!

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu problema puedes usar **Linq**.

```
var promedioA = (from c in colNumeros
                 where c >= 70
                 select c).Average();
```

Aquí recorremos el arreglo y filtramos solamente los elementos del arreglo **mayores o igual a 70**, y posteriormente hallamos el promedio aplicando la **función Average**.

Para hallar el promedio de los reprobados es la misma consulta lo único que ahora la condición de filtrado cambiaría a **c < 70**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```